# Why are many files appearing as 0B on external HFS+ hard drive?

Tags: external-hdd, hfs+

I am attempting to copy files from my OS X box into my new Linux box by way of an non-journaled HFS+ external hard drive. While most files copied over to the new machine just fine, I noticed a surprising number of empty files (0 bytes) that should not be. When the drive is mounted on the OS X machine, however, the files appear as expected. Running fsck did not fix the issue.

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the HFS+ file system can compresses files and replaces them with 0byte files (also called sparse files) that are like symbolic links.

you can use `du` with `--apparent-size` option to see the real size of those files.

Comment: Interesting.. are you aware of a method to "decompress" the filesystem? When I copy the files over from the HFS+ HD to the ext4 HD on the Linux box, it simply copies over the 0B file

Comment: I don't have a mac to test and i couldn't find any tools that do the job on linux , but i found that you can decompress them on your OS X box with `ditto --nohfsCompression [emptyf] [newfile]`. [ditto manual](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html)